# Get fragment of XML and display it as XML again

Tags: xml, abap

I am looking for a possibility to extract a part from an XML-file. The file is uploaded to the program by name, the text may vary but structure and node will stay the same. The XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n0:Content>
    <n1:Subnode1>
        <n1:Subnode2>
            <n1:Subnode3>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="en">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (EN)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="it">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (IT)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="fr">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (FR)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
            </n1:Subnode3>
        </n1:Subnode2>
    </n1:Subnode1>
</n0:Content>
```

That's the structure of the XML, which is uploaded to the Report. I want to extract by the lang=" ", and only display that exact part with the header 
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` as XML again.
So the output should look like this after I've decided for e.g. "en":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
            <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="en">
                    <head></head>
                    <body>
                        <p style="texttext">
                            <b>Text (EN)</b>
                        </p>
                    </body>
            </n1:Subnode4>
```

I've tried searching for something helpful for some time now so I'd be really thankful about some input. Thank you.

Comment: It's "a little" broad, there are many XML libraries. Can you tell us what you tried, you probably succeeded in something, at least partially, didn't you?

Comment: I've managed to upload the XML successfully, I've created a streamfactory and parsed it. I've been able to find something with "->find_from_name" but  I am not sure what exactly was found. Talking with my supervisor he said i should work with another factory to create a document, based on the last parts of "SAP_CONVERT_TO_XML_FORMAT". I'm not quite sure were to go from there tho.

Comment: This is another example where using XSLT would be the right choice.

Comment: @Jagger As you say, XSLT would be the better/easiest way to get the fragment, not iXML, would you post an answer?

Comment: @SandraRossi Frankly I tried and came to some issues regarding namespaces and had no more time to analyse what exactly the problem was. If I have a spare moment I will try to solve it and the post the answer.

Answer (score 2):

**1. Validate XML**

Make your XML valid. here's one option:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<n0:Content xmlns:n0="http://www.yourspace.com/n0" xmlns:n1="http://www.yourspace.com/n1" xmlns:n2="http://www.yourspace.com/n1">
    <n1:Subnode1>
        <n1:Subnode2>
            <n1:Subnode3>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="en">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (EN)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="it">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (IT)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
                <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="fr">
                        <head></head>
                        <body>
                            <p style="texttext">
                                <b>Text (FR)</b>
                            </p>
                        </body>
                </n1:Subnode4>
            </n1:Subnode3>
        </n1:Subnode2>
    </n1:Subnode1>
</n0:Content>
```

Repeat the same for the result (destination) `XML`.

**XSD Generation**

Generate an `XSD` from it (using tools like [this](http://xmlgrid.net/xml2xsd.html)). Possible result:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified">
         <!-- XML Schema Generated from XML Document on Thu Mar 21 2019 16:04:11 GMT+0200 (Israel Standard Time) -->
         <!-- with XmlGrid.net Free Online Service http://xmlgrid.net -->
         <xs:element name="n0:Content">
               <xs:complexType>
                     <xs:sequence>
                           <xs:element name="n1:Subnode1">
                                 <xs:complexType>
                                       <xs:sequence>
                                             <xs:element name="n1:Subnode2">
                                                   <xs:complexType>
                                                         <xs:sequence>
                                                               <xs:element name="n1:Subnode3">
                                                                     <xs:complexType>
                                                                           <xs:sequence>
                                                                                 <xs:element name="n1:Subnode4" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                                                                                       <xs:complexType>
                                                                                             <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                   <xs:element name="head"></xs:element>
                                                                                                   <xs:element name="body">
                                                                                                         <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                               <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                     <xs:element name="p">
                                                                                                                           <xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                       <xs:element name="b" type="xs:string"></xs:element>
                                                                                                                                 </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                                                 <xs:attribute name="style" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                                                           </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                                     </xs:element>
                                                                                                               </xs:sequence>
                                                                                                         </xs:complexType>
                                                                                                   </xs:element>
                                                                                             </xs:sequence>
                                                                                             <xs:attribute name="xml:lang" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                                                                                       </xs:complexType>
                                                                                 </xs:element>
                                                                           </xs:sequence>
                                                                     </xs:complexType>
                                                               </xs:element>
                                                         </xs:sequence>
                                                   </xs:complexType>
                                             </xs:element>
                                       </xs:sequence>
                                 </xs:complexType>
                           </xs:element>
                     </xs:sequence>
                     <xs:attribute name="xmlns:n0" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                     <xs:attribute name="xmlns:n1" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
                     <xs:attribute name="xmlns:n2" type="xs:string"></xs:attribute>
               </xs:complexType>
         </xs:element>
   </xs:schema>
```

Save the results in an `XSD` file, say `texts_source.xsd`.

Repeat the same for the result (destination) XML.

Save the results in an `XSD` file, say `en_text_destination.xsd`.

**Proxy object an data dictionary generation**

Generate [proxy object](https://help.sap.com/doc/saphelp_nw70/7.0.31/en-US/ab/585f3c482a7331e10000000a114084/content.htm?no_cache=true) and data dictionary. I am doing it with `SPROX_XSD2PROXY` program (if done often, you may wrap it with a transaction in `SE93`, i called it `ZXSD_GEN`). The parameters are:

1. Full path to the mentioned `XSD` file, say `d:\schemas\texts.xsd`.
2. Package that fits the prefix (`zsomthing` or `/something/`).
3. Prefix `zsomthing_anothersomthing` or `/something/anothersomthing`
4. Check the activation checkbox

Repeat the same for the result (destination) `XSD`.

**Program**

You can implement it with a class with four methods:

1. READ
2. TRANSFORM
3. WRITE
4. EXECUTE

*READ*

Get your XML data from anywhere then return it as `XSTRING`.

*TRANSFORM*

```
DATA: ls_source, ls_dest.  "a data of the root structure type of source XML
```

Call `CL_PROXY_XML_TRANSFORM=>XML_XSTRING_TO_ABAP` method.

parameters:

`DDIC_TYPE` - the name of root structure of source you generate in **Proxy object an data dictionary generation** section.
`XML` - XML data read.
`ABAP_DATA` - `ls_source`
th

Make your desired manipulation by filling the destination root structure.

Call `CL_PROXY_XML_TRANSFORM=>ABAP_TO_XML_XSTRING` method

parameters:

`ABAP_DATA` - `ls_dest`

`DDIC_TYPE` - the name of root structure of destination you generate in **Proxy object an data dictionary generation** section.

return the `XML` results (`XSTRING`)

*WRITE*

Save your XML data to anywhere.

*EXECUTE*

Call `READ`, then pass its results to `TRANSFORM`, then pass its results to `WRITE`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with iXML exclusively (which is quite complex compared to using an XSLT transformation, as said by Jagger).

iXML can handle nodes with namespaces only if they are declared (xmlns:prefix="URI").

iXML raises an error as soon as a change to the DOM tree leads to a namespace prefix not being declared (or used outside its declaration scope).

So, your XML should have the namespace declarations as follows so that it's a valid XML (as said by Dorad) and can be parsed by iXML, and note that `xmlns:n1=...` can also be moved inside `<n1:Subnode1>`:

```
<?xml ...?>
<n0:Content xmlns:n0="http://www.yourspace.com/n0" xmlns:n1="http://www.yourspace.com/n1">
  <n1:Subnode1>
    ...
</n0:Content>
```

The result should also have this minimal namespace declaration:

```
<?xml ...?>
<n1:Subnode4 xmlns:n1="http://www.yourspace.com/n1" xml:lang="en">
    ...
</n1:Subnode4>
```

By the way, you didn't tell if there can be several nodes with `xml:lang="en"`. I assume the answer is NO, or only the first matching node is to be selected.

Code:

```
DATA(xmlstr) = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`
&& `<n0:Content xmlns:n0="http://n0" xmlns:n1="http://n1">`
&& `  <n1:Subnode1>`
&& `    <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="en"><p style="texttext"><b>Text (EN)</b></p></n1:Subnode4>`
&& `    <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="it"><p style="texttext"><b>Text (IT)</b></p></n1:Subnode4>`
&& `    <n1:Subnode4 xml:lang="fr"><p style="texttext"><b>Text (FR)</b></p></n1:Subnode4>`
&& `  </n1:Subnode1>`
&& `</n0:Content>`.

DATA lo_document TYPE REF TO if_ixml_document.
CALL FUNCTION 'SDIXML_XML_TO_DOM'
  EXPORTING xml      = cl_proxy_service=>cstring2xstring( xmlstr )
  IMPORTING document = lo_document.

DATA(lo_element) = CAST if_ixml_element( lo_document->create_iterator_filtered(
                   lo_document->create_filter_attribute_ns( name = 'lang'
                   value = 'en' uri = 'xml' ) )->get_next( ) ).
DATA(lo_xmlns) = lo_element->get_namespace_context( ).
DATA(i) = 1.
WHILE i <= lo_xmlns->num_bindings( ) AND lo_xmlns->get_binding_prefix( i ) IS NOT INITIAL.
  lo_element->set_attribute_ns( prefix = 'xmlns'
        name = lo_xmlns->get_binding_prefix( i ) value = lo_xmlns->get_binding_uri( i ) ).
  i = i + 1.
ENDWHILE.

DATA(lo_new_document) = cl_ixml=>create( )->create_document( ).
lo_new_document->set_version( lo_document->get_version( ) ).
lo_new_document->set_encoding( lo_document->get_encoding( ) ).

DATA(lo_fragment) = lo_new_document->create_document_fragment( ).
lo_fragment->append_child( lo_element ).
lo_new_document->append_child( lo_fragment ).

DATA(lo_doc) = NEW cl_xml_document( ). lo_doc->create_with_dom( lo_new_document ).
lo_doc->display( ).
```

Result:

[image]

Notes about the code:

- There is a method `get_namespace_context` but nothing dedicated to "set the namespace context", it's why the method `set_attribute_ns` is used to set the `xmlns` attributes.
- To simplify the code, I have set all `xmlns` attributes directly in the original element instead of first cloning; I should have better done `DATA(lo_new_element) = lo_element->clone( )` and then change lo_new_element only.
- iXML doesn't handle the XML header as an iXML node, there are specific methods to initialize it, so I simulate a copy with methods `set_version`, `set_encoding`, ...
- I used a dummy node of type `if_ixml_document_fragment` because the root of the new document can only be a node created from this document itself, i.e. it's impossible to set `lo_element` (from the original document) as the root of the new document.
- To simplify the demonstration, I didn't handle the errors.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will try it immediatly. As you assumed, there can only be one subnode with "EN", "IT" etc.

Comment: Hello Sandra!
I got another question. My XML-document got a lot of namespace declarations and when i check the code it says "literals that take up more than one line are not permitted" how can i fix this?

Comment: @D.Ge. It's an ABAP syntax error. I guess you've got a missing quote at the end of one ABAP line (a literal cannot overlap several lines). It's not related to XML, it's just related to a text literal with any content.